# Python subprocess, kill process after timed delay

Tags: python, audio, delay, nonblocking

I'm working with Python and Raspberry Pi for the first time (it's a Pi 2) and trying to trigger a timed set of commands. I've got most of it figured out except the very end, where I want to kill all processes.

The logic is as follows:

-- Trigger an audio file (.wav) called "countdown"

-- Trigger another audio file (.wav) called "dixie"

-- While dixie is playing trigger a wget command to trigger a photo on my camera

-- Keep playing "dixie" until the previous wget finishes executing

-- When wget finishes executing, stop playing "dixie"

-- Trigger final audio file (.wav) called "applause"

-- **Stop all audio**

Essentially, the wget is the important one, the audio files playing are just to create music while my camera takes a photo. When the wget has finished, and the applause finishes, I want to kill all the audio, but the subprocess.Popen command for "dixie" continues to play (it's about 40 seconds long). How can I kill this process at the end?

Here is my code so far:

```
import os
import time
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["aplay countdown.wav"], shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(["aplay dixie.wav"], shell=True)
subprocess.call(["wget 'http://10.5.5.9/camera/SH?t=12345678&p=%01' -O-"], shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.call(["aplay applause.wav"], shell=True)
subprocess.Popen.kill(["aplay dixie.wav"], shell=True)
```

I want to kill "dixie" once "applause" has finished playing.

My code yields the error:

```
"unbound method kill() must be called with Popen instance as first
argument (got list instance instead)"
```

Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["aplay dixie.wav"], shell=True)

# do something 

proc.terminate()
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! this doesn't work, though. "Dixie" continues to play after "applause" has finished.