# Set a Timer for a function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, args, osascript

I have a collection of songs and I'd like to have them played in sequence.

If I run the `function` below, it will play milliseconds of each song but **only the last one on the list in its entirety**.

```
def play(*args):
    for id_ in args:
        print 'playing', id_
        os.system("osascript -e 'tell application \"Spotify\" to play track \"%s\"'" % (id_,))
```

what can I add to the `function` in order to tell the `system` to play all song `ids` (the `args`) for an ammount of time `t`?

Comment: Use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) instead of `os.system`. That way you can wait for the process to complete before looping again. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470759/python-subprocess-kill-process-after-timed-delay)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
import time

def play(t=1, *args):
    for id_ in args:
        print 'playing', id_
        os.system("osascript -e 'tell application \"Spotify\" to play track \"%s\"'" % (id_,))
        time.sleep(t)
```

#### Explanation

`time.sleep(t)` sleeps for t seconds.